# 1D Bayesian Inference clarification

Tags: bayesian, likelihood, prior, posterior, odds-ratio

I'd like some help making sure I understand a 1D Bayesian inference problem.

Say I have a data vector which is an array of the number of flu cases reported weekly in California for the past 10 years.

I want to compare two models which describe this data, via the odds ratio: $$\mathcal{O}_{ij} = \frac{P(M_i|D,I)}{P(M_j|D,I)} = \frac{P(M_i|I)\,\mathcal{L}(M_i)}{P(M_j|I)\,\mathcal{L}(M_j)}$$ where $$\mathcal{L}(M) = \int d\theta P(\theta|M_i)\mathcal{L}(\theta)|D,M)$$ borrowing the notation I've found. $M$ is model, $D$ is data, I'm not sure what $I$ represents.

I've developed two models, each of which are 1D vectors, one of which has parameters.

I'm new to Bayesian statistics. My confusion here is: what are $\mathcal{L}(\theta)|D,M)$, $P(M|I)$, and $P(D|I)$ in relation to the dataset and the two models? I Think $P(D|I)$ is just the data. $P(M|I)$ is the prior but I don't know what that relates too, unless that's the model, in which case I don't know what the likelihood function $\mathcal{L}$ is.

Could someone help clarify this for me?

Comment: You say "borrowing the notation I've found." - where did you find this notation?

Comment: if you have never heard of a likelihood function, you should definitely invest in reading an introductory  mathematical statistics or Bayesian statistics book.

Comment: Notation is found from course notes. I've heard of a likelihood function. I just want some clarification with what it relates to in a 1D model.